# Change name from this@ on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, alias, extension-function

I have the follow situation, an extension function named as `save` from `Marker`

**1. The code**

```
fun Marker.save(ctx: Context) {
    //database is an extension property from Context
    ctx.database.use {
        insert("markers",
                "id" to this@save.id,
                "latitude" to this@save.position.latitude,
                "longitude" to this@save.position.longitude,
                "name" to this@save.title)
    }
}
```

The code work fine to me.

**2. The issue**

To use the instance of `Marker` inside `save` method I need use `this@save`, but this name is not sugestive, in first view, it don't appear like `Marker`.

**3. The question**

Is possible apply an alias to use instead `this@save`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just save the reference to a well-named local variable:

```
fun Marker.save(ctx: Context) {
    val marker = this
    //database is an extension property from Context
    ctx.database.use {
        insert("markers",
                "id" to marker.id,
                "latitude" to marker.position.latitude,
                "longitude" to marker.position.longitude,
                "name" to marker.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: I used it, but I thought that maybe exists another way to do @zsmb13. Thanks!

Comment: thanks again, but see my own answer. Sorry for any problem caused for me!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @zsmb13 for support, but I need answer with my own answer because everythings that we doing are unecessary, just use the property itself, without any prefix, look this:

```
fun Marker.save(ctx: Context) {
    //database is an extension property from Context
    ctx.database.use {
        insert("markers",
                "id" to id, //without any prefix
                "latitude" to position.latitude,
                "longitude" to position.longitude,
                "name" to title)
    }
}
```

I fell embarrassed for this, but I go keep my question to support another developer. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Indeed, using the outer `this` implicitly is also an option. Worth noting that this can get quite confusing when you are nested multiple scopes deep and you're grabbing something from an outer one. (And of course, it only works as long as no inner scopes have the same properties.)

Answer (score 0):

`.let` is an option:

```
fun Marker.save() = this.let { marker ->
    ctx.database.use {
      insert("markers",
        "id" to marker.id,
        // etc
      )
    }
}
```